# Preview document using UIDocumentInteractionController doesn't work in iOS 13

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsurl, ios13, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

I use the UIDocumentInteractionController to preview files of different types within the app. This has worked fine in the past, but when running the app on a device with iOS 13 the document is not presented. What is shown is the file name and type.

I have looked for similar questions and found this
[UIDocumentInteractionController showing file name and file type , not file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37936259/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-showing-file-name-and-file-type-not-file-conte)

I've tried `NSUrl.CreateFileUrl(FilePath, null)` as the comments on that question suggest but this doesn't solve the issue.

This is what I use for opening the file and presenting the preview:

```
var uidic = UIDocumentInteractionController.FromUrl(new NSUrl(FilePath, true));
uidic.Delegate = new DocInteractionC(navcontroller);
uidic.PresentPreview(true);
```

And the controller definition:

```
public class DocInteractionC : UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate
{
    readonly UIViewController m_oParentViewController;

    public DocInteractionC(UIViewController controller)
    {
        m_oParentViewController = controller;
    }

    public override UIViewController ViewControllerForPreview(UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
    {
        return m_oParentViewController;
    }

    public override UIView ViewForPreview(UIDocumentInteractionController controller)
    {
        return m_oParentViewController.View;
    }
}
```

Is it possible this is an issue with NSUrl in Xamarin.ios for iOS 13? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does it work on a real device but gives the error in simulator? If so, are you able to log into iCloud in the simulator can't access iCloud Drive through the Files app?

Comment: The issue occurs on a real iOS 13 device, though I haven't been able to debug a device running iOS 13, I only have an iOS 12 device, but I get the same behaviour that was reported in the iOS 13 simulator.

Comment: Looks like the file isn't recognized correctly. If I open an XLSX file and press the share button on the top right corner it doesn't show Numbers or Excel as possible share targets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My issue was solved by modifying the code as followed:

```
var uidic = new UIDocumentInteractionController()
{
  Name = fileName,
  Url = NSUrl.FromFilename(filePath),
  Delegate = new DocInteractionC(viewController)
};

uidic.PresentPreview(true);
```

Larger files, like an 11MB XLSX file, will take very long to load.

Comment: Tested on physical iPad 13.1.2 and simulator iPhone XR 12.4

Comment: Thanks! NSUrl.FromFileName(filePath) instead of new NSUrl(filePath,true) do the trick.

Comment: we are getting the same issue in iPhone and simulator both. can you tell me filePath format?

Comment: @SumitMishra We are writing data to var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), fileName); then open it with the same url.